# awk for 'any' character in (file 1) in (file 2)

Tags: shell, variables, awk

What's the best approach to awk for any character included in a filename in (file 1) in (file 2) ?

Code so far:

```
$ sed -e 's/.*\ -\ //' -e 's/.mp3$//' File1.txt | while read z; do tit="$z" ; awk -v title="$tit" '{FS = "\t"} $2 ~ title {print $0}' File2.txt ; done
```

Result;
It's working except when it hits the file with ( in the filename.

I've tried single and double quoting everything I can think of, still no luck.

**File1**: named "Playlist", delimiter is: " - "

- Peter Tosh - Na Goa Jail (Bonus Track).mp3

File1 fields are: "Artist" "Title"

**File2:** named "Master-List", delimiter is: tab

- Peter Tosh Na Goa Jail 32000 /Music/Peter Tosh/Peter Tosh - Na Goa Jail (Bonus Track.mp3

File2 fields are: "Artist" "Title" "Bitrate" "Path"

Using the above examples... for each entry in "Playlist"

1. Use "Playlist" to produce 2 variables for Field1 and Field2 (artist title)
2. Search for $title "Na Goa Jail (Bonus Track).mp3" inside Master-List
3. If matched, check that the $artist also is matched
4. if the $title and $artist match, print the 4th colunm in Master-List, else print "No Match".

Comment: +1 for excellent first post, but ... ;-) please add your expected output. (Inputs and outputs are easier to read when formatted as code). Good luck.

Comment: Set your field separator only once using either `-F "\t"` or `BEGIN { FS = "\t"}` instead of every time a line is read.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same (and simpler) by doing:

```
sed -e 's/.*\ -\ //' -e 's/.mp3$//' File1.txt | while IFS='\n' read z; do grep "$z" File2.txt; done
```

Notice the use of IFS (Internal Field Separator) for the loop, which is by default *space*.

Comment: Thanks. Can either of you correct the code I used to use (awk) to ignore characters like ()-$%#@! in the filenames ? In my example, I'm searching the song name "Peter Tosh - Reggae Party (Bonus).mp3" inside file2. If matched, will return the entire line in file2. The parentheses (and probably other characters) are tripping awk. I need to use awk as a one-liner. Thank you.

Comment: Your approach is not going to work because you are using $z as a regular expression (when using ~).  In such case, you should escape those special characters in awk, but that will result in a longer 'one-liner'.  It would be easier to help you if you explain more what do you want to accomplish and why it has to be in one-line of awk.

Comment: I edited the original post to explain more. Thanks. Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR == FNR { artist[$1,$2]=1 ; next }          #Load the artiest/title file
     NR != FNR { if( artist[$1,$2] ) { print $4 }  #Check if artiest,title was loaded
                 else { print "no match" } }' artist-title artist-title-bitrate-path
```